# How to test an async void method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await

Please consider the code as shown below. By calling GetBrands, property Brands will be assigned with proper data.

```
public class BrandsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IEnumerable<Brand> _brands;
    public IEnumerable<Brand> Brands
    {
        get { return _brands; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _brands, value); }
    }

    public async void GetBrands()
    {
        // ......

        Brands = await _dataHelper.GetFavoriteBrands();

        // ......
    }
}
```

But if I test it as shown below, the test failed. How do I wait for the async call inside method GetBrands?

```
[TestMethod]
public void AllBrandsTest()
{
    BrandsViewModel viewModel = new BrandsViewModel();
    viewModel.GetBrands();
    Assert.IsTrue(viewModel.Brands.Any());
}
```

Comment: Please read / view this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/02/18/talk-the-new-async-design-patterns.aspx It basically says: Don't use `async void` except for event handlers.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thank you, Daniel. I refactored my code, and it just work like a charm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer here is: don't make it an `async void`. In fact, don't **ever** make something an `async void` unless it absolutely has to be to work as an event-handler. The things that `async void` loses are ***precisely*** the things that you want here for your test (and presumably for your real code).

Make it an `async Task` method instead, and you now have the ability to wait for completion (with timeout) / add a continuation, and to check whether it exited with success or an exception.

This is a single word change, to:

```
public async Task GetBrands()
{
    // ......

    Brands = await _dataHelper.GetFavoriteBrands();

    // ......
}
```

and then in the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task AllBrandsTest()
{
    BrandsViewModel viewModel = new BrandsViewModel();
    var task = viewModel.GetBrands();
    Assert.IsTrue(task.Wait(YOUR_TIMEOUT), "failed to load in time");
    Assert.IsTrue(viewModel.Brands.Any(), "no brands");
}
```

Comment: Why did you keep the test `async`, if you don't use `await` in it?

Comment: @svick that is a question for the OP, who also doesn't `await` in it :)

Comment: @svick My fault. I have corrected my test code. It's not necessary to keep async if no await in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Your model (a DTO) is populating itself (data access). This is too much for one class to do. Usually when you ask yourself *"How on earth can I test this"*, it's time for refactoring. Create a separate data access class:

```
BrandsViewModel viewModel = new BrandsViewModel();
var brandAccess = new BrandsDataAccess();
viewModel.Brands = await brandAccess.GetAllBrands();
Assert.IsTrue(viewModel.Brands.Any());
```

Now you can test `BrandsDataAccess.GetAllBrands()`.

Comment: Where did `async` go? What I mean: the original code is `async`, yours isn't, so I don't think it's a good replacement.

Comment: @svick it's the principle that matters, not the implementation. See edit.

Comment: @CodeCaster Would you please explain your point further more? In terms of Single Responsibility Principle, I think populate its own property within the same class is acceptable. Isn't it?

Comment: @Shinbo no, a data _transfer_ object (which a (view)model is) should not be concerned with data _access_.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for clarifying it. What is the side effect if a DTO contains data access logic?